# Global inbox is giving me an error page

Tags: bug, global-inbox, network-profile

I can access my user profile, and view all the tabs execpt for the inbox one.

I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!", and a cute panda falling off a slide.

The url bar shows this:

[stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/3203697/tim](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/3203697/tim)

It isn't just the profile page link that is broken, it also the Chrome notifications - I get them but clicking on them takes me to the error page as well.